# extract value after every colon with duplicate words in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I am having difficulty extract value from my data.I have a column that looks like:

```
 Name Group  Note
 ENG1 AR1  　regio regnum, domain kingdom: 271  ratio%:   23.9  regio phylum, domain phylum: 328  ratio%:   46.7  
 ENG2 AR2  　regio regnum, domain kingdom: 543  ratio%:   63.9  regio phylum, domain phylum: 104  ratio%:   11.9  
 ENG3 AR2  　regio regnum, domain kingdom: 669  ratio%:   71.1  regio phylum, domain phylum: 703  ratio%:   82.4  
 ENG5 AR1  　regio regnum, domain kingdom: 306  ratio%:   44.4  regio phylum, domain phylum: 641  ratio%:   76.5  
 ENG6 AR4  　regio regnum, domain kingdom: 802  ratio%:   89.7  regio phylum, domain phylum:  12  ratio%:   3.4  
 ENG7 AR4  　regio regnum, domain kingdom: 175  ratio%:   10.6  regio phylum, domain phylum: 528  ratio%:   57.2
```

I would like to extract the value after every colon.Data have duplicate words `ratio%`

Here is my code I have tried,but not go through well :

```
str_extract(x, "(?<=regio regnum, domain kingdom: )(.*)(?= ratio%)")
```

And I want to get like this:

```
  Name Group regio regnum, domain kingdom ratio% regio phylum, domain phylum ratio%
1 ENG1 AR1                            271   23.9                         328   46.7
2 ENG2 AR2                            543   63.9                         104   11.9
3 ENG3 AR2                            669   71.1                         703   82.4
4 ENG5 AR1                            306   44.4                         641   76.5
5 ENG6 AR4                            802   89.7                          12    3.4
6 ENG7 AR4                            175   10.6                         528   57.2
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Please share a reproducible example ("reprex") of your _existing_ data, by pasting the output from `dput(head(existing_data, n = 10))`.  If possible, also do the same for your intended _result_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit clunky but does the job:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
dat <- data.frame(x = c("regio regnum, domain kingdom: 271  ratio%:   23.9  regio phylum, domain phylum: 328  ratio%:   46.7"))

dat %>% 
  separate(col=x, into=c(LETTERS[1:5]), sep=":") %>%
  mutate(regio_regnum_domain_kindgdom = parse_number(.$B),
         DKratio = parse_number(.$C),
         regio_phylum_domain_phylum = parse_number(.$D),
         DPratio = E) %>% 
  select(c(regio_regnum_domain_kindgdom, DKratio, regio_phylum_domain_phylum, DPratio))
#>   regio_regnum_domain_kindgdom DKratio regio_phylum_domain_phylum DPratio
#> 1                          271    23.9                        328    46.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>